# Django aggregated field error on returning

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I'm stubbling on a problem where I'm no longer shure if I'm doing something wrong or there is something wrong with the package.

I have a custom ordering filter of django-filter:

```
class CustomOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.extra['choices'] += [
            ('trainingDates', 'Training Dates'),
            ('-trainingDates', 'Training Dates (descending)'),
        ]

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if any(v in ['trainingDates', '-trainingDates'] for v in value):
            data = qs.annotate(first_date=Min('training_dates__date')).order_by('first_date')
            return data
        return super().filter(qs, value)
```

When I add a debug point add the return statement I can see the field 'first_date' but when I continue I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2020-02-20 14:00:45,047 utils 24233 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 487, in _resolve_from_executor
    executor(resolve, reject)
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 754, in executor
    return resolve(f(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphql/execution/middleware.py", line 75, in make_it_promise
    return next(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphene_django/filter/fields.py", line 107, in connection_resolver
    **args
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphene_django/fields.py", line 164, in connection_resolver
    return on_resolve(iterable)
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphene_django/fields.py", line 118, in resolve_connection
    pageinfo_type=PageInfo,
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphql_relay/connection/arrayconnection.py", line 88, in connection_from_list_slice
    for i, node in enumerate(_slice)
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1087, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 474, in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 55, in pre_sql_setup
    order_by = self.get_order_by()
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 330, in get_order_by
    field, self.query.get_meta(), default_order=asc))
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 704, in find_ordering_name
    field, targets, alias, joins, path, opts, transform_function = self._setup_joins(pieces, opts, alias)
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 734, in _setup_joins
    field, targets, opts, joins, path, transform_function = self.query.setup_joins(pieces, opts, alias)
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1504, in setup_joins
    names[:pivot], opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True,
  File "/home/bart/projects/coursemanager/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1420, in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: Cannot resolve keyword 'first_date' into field. Choices are: amount, comment, company, confirmed, course_name, deleted, email, first_name, function, id, invoice, last_name, phone_number, present, reminder, training_dates, unregistered_dates
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? What I want is to order by the first date in a many-to-many relation. If you want to see more of the code let me know.

Edit #1: Model registration

```
class RegistrationManager(models.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(deleted__isnull=True)


class Registration(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    email = models.EmailField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)

    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    invoice = models.BooleanField()

    company = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    function = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)

    confirmed = models.BooleanField()
    reminder = models.BooleanField()
    present = models.BooleanField()

    training_dates = models.ManyToManyField('training.TrainingDate', related_name='registrations')
    unregistered_dates = models.ManyToManyField('training.TrainingDate', related_name='unregistered_registrations',
                                                blank=True)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)

    comment = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    deleted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = RegistrationManager.as_manager()

    def delete(self):
        self.deleted = datetime.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} ({})".format(self.first_name, self.last_name, self.company)
```

Comment: Can you include the model you are querying it?

Comment: I edited the question to include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you used graphene and found this [issue](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/173) in graphene. Seems like it has been fixed in this [PR](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/pull/194).
So probably updating graphene to version 2 would fix the issue.